# error: no matching function call when adding parameters to class constructor

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments

I have a class, "a", that has an instance of class "b". The following code gives the error in the title of the question, but when I change b to not take any arguments, the code runs without errors.

```
class b
{
public:
    b(int);
};

class a
{
  public:
  b bObj;
      a(int arg1, const std::string& arg2);
};

a::a(int arg1, const std::string& arg2){
  bObj = b(5);
}

b::b(int IDD2){
  srand(time(0)+IDD2);
}
```

Running this code where "b" has no arguments works, but I actually need to pass in a value. Why is it giving this error?

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of `a`, `bObj` must be constructed before you enter the function body. But there is no zero argument constructor for `b`, and you have not provided a default initializer, so you get an error.

Instead, you can initialize `bObj` before reaching the body of the constructor by using a member initializer list:

```
a::a(int arg1, const std::string& arg2) : bObj(5) {}
```

Or provide the default inside the class:

```
class a
{
  public:
  b bObj = 5;
  a(int arg1, const std::string& arg2);
};
```

Comment: I see. The syntax for the second case is strange to me. What if there were multiple integer arguments. Would I use the following?
b bObj = 5, 2;

Comment: @MrMultiMediator You could do `b bObj{5, 2};`